# Create custom throwable class in Yii2 or Native PHP

Tags: php, oop, exception, yii2

I was on my way create an API, but I want to create a throwable class, for example I want to execute something like this `throw new Response(400, 'Invalid Token')` which I wanted to return like this

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Token"
}
```

I trying to make the class extended to error or throwable class, but the result keep returning the stack-trace, line and etc.

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\scoring\components;

use Yii;

class Response extends \Exception implements \Throwable {

  public $httpCode;
  public $message;

  public static function set(int $http, array $data = []) {
    $data = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge($data, [
      'server_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]);
    Yii::$app->response->statusCode = $http;
    $old = isset(Yii::$app->response->data) ? Yii::$app->response->data : [];
    return Yii::$app->response->data = array_merge($old, $data);
  }

  public static function setNonAjaxRequestError() {
    return self::set(400, [
      'code' => 400,
      'message' => 'Request Must Use HttpRequest'
    ]);
  }

  public function __construct($httpCode, $message) {
    unset($this->line);
    $this->httpCode = $httpCode;
    $this->message = $message;
  }

}
```

Trying using yii2 class like HttpException its always returned with its type property is there a way that I could achieve the result that I wanted?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-handling-errors#error-format But you may learn how `ErrorHandler` format exceptions https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/ErrorHandler.php#L144 and make it your own. Or I recommended don't change it and just set correct headers for JSON reponse.